# I want to check the color at the coordinate of my click with canvas but I only get black no matter where I click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I have a react js application and I use canvas to draw squares on it. Each square has a particular color and I want when I click on it I can retrieve the color so that I can continue my program.
But no matter where I click I always get the same thing: black. While I click on for example a green square.

Here is my program to recover the color at the positioning of the click.

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      console.log("hola")
      const x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      const y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
      const imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 10, 10);
      console.log(imageData);
      console.log(x, y, "x/y");
      const pixelData = imageData.data;
      console.log(
        `Rouge : ${pixelData[0]}, Vert : ${pixelData[1]}, Bleu : ${pixelData[2]}, Alpha : ${pixelData[3]}`
      );

    }, false);
```

And this is my output with the coordonate from the click.

[image]

And this is an other click in other place in my canvas.

[image]

Like you see i have for value 0 0 0 0 instead of my color

Comment: Can you add the HTML? Since you are using `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`, if you nested inside another element this will not work. Try using things like `getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: I don't really have any html, everything is react compoments
but this is how i define my canvas
the css


`canvas{
    position:  absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(128, 199, 71);
}`
And my canvas



`function Village() {
  return (
    <canvas id="myVillage"></canvas>
  );
} 
export default Village;
`

Comment: React also outputs HTML, and your absolute positioning relies on either the document's relative positive or the enclosing elements position. There is HTML you will have to include in order to accurately help you. My answer should work on any canvas, though, as it normalises the value and then computes where on the canvas you have clicked. The fact that your canvas is being stretched by CSS (width: 100%, although the `[width]` attribute overwrites that I think), you will have to use a technique like I proposed in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to map the click onto the canvas (whos `width` and `height` might differ from the actual display size) you would need to first normalize the click's position and then multiply it by the `height` and `width`. First, you need a `getBoundingClientRect()`, as its coordinates are in the same space as `clientX` and `clientY`. Then you can use this math to get the exact pixel coordinates on the canvas the click represents:

```
(client - bb.offset( / bb.size * canvas.size
```

Then sample just a *single* pixel and not a 10x10 grid to get the exact clicked color.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

// Create some example color we can sample

const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

gradient.addColorStop( 0, 'red' );
gradient.addColorStop( 1, 'blue' );

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

canvas.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
      
  const bb = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = Math.floor((event.clientX - bb.left) / bb.width * canvas.width);
  const y = Math.floor((event.clientY - bb.top) / bb.height * canvas.height);
  const [ r, g, b, a ] = ctx.getImageData( x, y, 1, 1 ).data;
  const color =  `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
  
  console.log({ color, r, g, b, a })
  
  document.body.style.background = color;
  
})
```

```html
<canvas width=300 height=300></canvas>
```